# Pivot columns with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Table #Temp:

```
ID    Name        Hobbies
1     xxx          Reading
1     xxx          Sports
1     xxx          Dance
2     xyz          Dance
3     yyy          Swimming
3     yyy          Reading
```

Now, I want the result set to be:

```
ID   Name    Hobby1     Hobby2    Hobby3 
1    xxx     Reading    Sports    Dance         
2    xyz     Cooking                  
3    yyy     Coloring   Swimming
```

How to accomplish this? I have used multiple values of hobbies so I can't hard-code.

Comment: Search for `Dynamic Pivot`

Comment: Assume I have the max num of 3 hobbies.. so no need to have dynamic pivot i guess..

Comment: You have mentioned *I have used multiple values of hobbies so I can't hard-code.* Plus if you know the max number of hobbies then search for `Pivot` in `Sql Server`

Comment: I meant there are more number of hobbies like cooking, reading, swimming, coloring, .....etc., but for each member, there will be max of 3.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions on that matter, here on SO. In this question: no attempts, no effort, no searches for solution. Even MSDN article about [pivoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) gives the basic explanation and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the max number of hobbies for each name You can generate row Number for each name and use it for pivoting

```
;with data as
(
SELECT row_number()over(partition by [ID] order by [Hobbies])rn,*
FROM   ( VALUES (1,'xxx','Reading'),
                (1,'xxx','Sports'),
                (1,'xxx','Dance'),
                (2,'xyz','Dance'),
                (3,'yyy','Swimming'),
                (3,'yyy','Reading')) tc ([ID], [Name], [Hobbies])
)
SELECT [ID],
       [Name],
       [Hobby1] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Hobbies] END),
       [Hobby2] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [Hobbies] END),
       [Hobby3] = Max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [Hobbies] END)
FROM   data
GROUP  BY [ID],
          [Name]
```

**Result :**

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║ Hobby1  ║  Hobby2  ║ Hobby3 ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ xxx  ║ Dance   ║ Reading  ║ Sports ║
║  2 ║ xyz  ║ Dance   ║ NULL     ║ NULL   ║
║  3 ║ yyy  ║ Reading ║ Swimming ║ NULL   ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100),Hobbies VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'xxx','Reading')
,(1,'xxx','Sports')
,(1,'xxx','Dance')
,(2,'xyz','Dance')
,(3,'yyy','Swimming')
,(3,'yyy','Reading');

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,'Hobby' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.Name ORDER BY tbl.ID) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnName
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Hobbies) FOR ColumnName IN(Hobby1,Hobby2,Hobby3,Hobby4 /*add more if needed*/)
) AS p
```

The result

```
ID  Name    Hobby1   Hobby2  Hobby3 Hobby4
1   xxx     Reading  Sports   Dance NULL
2   xyz     Dance    NULL     NULL  NULL
3   yyy     Swimming Reading  NULL  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.....

```
            select ID  , Name  ,  Hobby1    , Hobby2  ,  Hobby3 
             from
             (
             select 
            ID , Name,Hobbies, 
                case when Hobyno ='1' then 'Hobby1' 
                when Hobyno ='2' then 'Hobby2' 
                when Hobyno ='3' then 'Hobby3' 
                else null end as HobyNo 
            from

            (
             select   *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION  BY id order by id ) HobyNo
              from   #temp
            )a
            where a.HobyNo <4  -- Add if you want more than 3 hobbie also edit case when
             )a 

            pivot
            (
              max(Hobbies)
              for Hobyno in ([Hobby1],[Hobby2],[Hobby3] )
            ) piv;
```

Comment: It works as expected. Can I do the same thing for 2 columns like hobbies as well as qualifications. ie., qual1, qual2

Comment: Ok. Give sample code with table structre and Desired O/p

Comment: #Table:  ID   Name  Hobbies  Qualifications

Comment: @Nandy There are two ways for `PIVOT`. *Old-fashioned* with `GROUP BY` and `MAX(CASE ...)` as in Prdp's answer and explicit `PIVOT` like in my answer. The above combines both for no reason...

Comment: @Shnugo - and it has been chosen as answer :D

Comment: @Nandy - Your new requirement for pivoting two columns can be easily handled through my approach.. If you want pivot syntax then you need to use pivot twice

Comment: @Prdp, You are right, that your approach is best to pivot more than one column. +1 to you...

Comment: @Prdp, your approach had helped me.. Thanks!